# IS March Security upates for sharepoint 2013 included in March 12, 2019, cumulative update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB4462219)?

Tags: 2013, cumulative-update

when I install [March 12, 2019, cumulative update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB4462219)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462219/march-12-2019-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2013) in SharePoint farm there is no need to separate install [Description of the security update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013: March 12, 2019.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462202/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server)

Here I want to fix the CVE-2019-0604 | Microsoft SharePoint Remote Code Execution Vulnerability in my SharePoint 2013 farm.

Comment: CU includes security updates and every other update from previous months. So there is no need to install SU after installing and applying the CU for the same month. (if not stated otherwise by MS).

Comment: @Christoffer add that as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

CU includes security updates and every other update from previous months. So there is no need to install a SU separately after installing and applying a CU for the same month. (if not stated otherwise by MS).